# How to have flutter show different screens based on whether or not firestore documents exist?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am pretty new to flutter and are designing an app that requires user to login. Once users have registered an account they will be required to fill out some user information before being taken to the home screen. If the user registers an account however doesnt fill out their info the next time they log in they should be returned to this screen. Currently, there is a stream that watches the value of the user. If this value is null then it shows the login page, otherwise it will show the home page.

I am having trouble implementing the user information screen. Would setting up a stream that watches a firestore document and, if the document exists return the home page, otherwise show the user infromation screen be the best method and if so how would I go about doing so?

Here is my code that checks whether or not the user is signed in:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

     return StreamProvider<User>.value(
       value: AuthService().user,
       child: MaterialApp(
      home: SignedIn(),
     )
     );
  }
```

And the code for the SignedIn() widget:

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);

     if (user == null) {
      return Authenticate();
    } else {
        return Home();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would probably try something like this.

```
StreamSubscription _subscription;

_subscription = yourStream.listen((data) {
  // navigate to whatever screen depending on the data
  if(data.signedIn){
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, "whatever_route"); 
  }
});
```